# Looking for alternative to "opened a can of worms"

Tags: phrase-requests

Looking for alternative to "opened a can of worms" in the following sentence...

It needs to be graphical enough for a young readership to grasp, a readership that won't have heard of Pandora's box or even know what a can of worms is.

> Having fixed one friend's laptop I wondered if I may have opened a can of worms and now all my friends will expect the same service.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What particular difference do you want the alternative to convey?

Comment: Pandora's box implies unknown evils and miseries, it is also something my readership may not know about. I want a more graphical similie to convey a regretful but understandable annoyance. I also don't want to imply my friends are worms!

Comment: "Opened a can of worms" is a metaphor, not simile, for *invited trouble* or *dug my own grave*.

Comment: My feeling is that _opening a can  of worms_ implies doing something likely to lead to unexpected problems/complications, while your friends expecting you to help them too is an entirely predictable result. Perhaps [open the floodgates](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/to-open-the-floodgates)?

Comment: Are you looking for another idiom or would a simple statement suffice?  ... may have created a problem for myself.

Comment: A simile would be easier for a younger readership to grasp so that it doesn't distract them from what they are reading and thus maintain their flow rather than they have to stop to consider what the metaphor means or indeed what a can of worms is.

Comment: Opening the floodgates implies a problematic surge rather than what is more likely to be a persistent trickle.

An idiom is preferred to liven up the sentence compared to a simple statement.

Comment: @SteveShute You're thinking too literally; the idiomatic meaning of "open the floodgates" is more general ([either something that's more frequent or more severe](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/to-open-the-floodgates)).

Comment: How young are your readers that they can understand the rest of the concepts in your sentence but not understand "can of worms"?

Comment: You’ll become the go-to guy for every tech-challenged kid on the block.